# Loan Terminology

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific term in the banking industry for a loan that is not yet fully paid-off?  Is it considered "open" or "active" or what?

*(if the correct answer contains more than one word, that is Okay.)*

Comment: This site expects at least a modicum of research. Try typing the sentence in your question title into a search engine and see what resources pop up.

Comment: I disagree with putting this question on hold. A dictionary can explain what a given word means, but only a thesaurus can list possible words and phrases to express a given meaning. In a specialized field, there are frequently one or more dictionaries, but seldom even one thesaurus. It was implied that a search engine would have given the correct answer. I am curious to know what site was intended and what keywords were used to find that site.

Comment: @Clare  Thank you for your comments.  You are correct. I google'd the post title and got the information I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's **outstanding**:

> remaining to be paid, done, or dealt with
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/outstanding)</sub>

For example:

> A loan in default that has not been offset is still an **outstanding loan**.
>   <sub>[IRS Issues Final Rules on Plan Loans](http://www.retire.prudential.com/media/managed/CPA1100.pdf)</sub>